# How to reference series in Highcharts v.4?

Tags: highcharts

In the current version of Highcharts, I can instantiate a chart with a line like this:

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart(chartOptions);
```

And then I can update the data with JavaScript like this:

```
chart.series[0].setData(...)
```

However, I'm now working on a project that uses HighchartsJS version 4.1.6, and I can't instantiate a chart with `Highcharts.chart(...)`.  Instead, it seems to be integrated with JQuery; the code instantiates a chart like so:

```
$('#container').highcharts(chartOptions)
```

And I'm not clear on how to reference the chart, or assign it to a variable so I can access its `series` array.  I need to be able to change the data with something like `setData()`, so here's my question: **In this older version of HighchartsJS how can I get a reference or handle on the chart object and change its data?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Highcharts.Chart()` constructor or refer to a chart created with jQuery in the below way:

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(...);

var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
});

// chart 1
console.log(chart1);
// chart 2
console.log(chart2.highcharts());
// or just
console.log($('#container2').highcharts());
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/om4Lqp5x/

Comment: Aha, the capital "C" makes the difference!